# React-Native Firebase Image upload Expo

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, expo

I am trying to upload an image to firebase storage however I am getting the error `object Object` as shown below

Please may someone help me I have never uploaded an image to firebase and really need assistance . Any help what's so ever will be much appreciated. Thank you sooo much in advance!!!!!

This is my code. I've Initialized firebase as well as my image path `postImage` works as expected.

```
const handleSubmit = () => {
    if (postImage !== undefined) {
        const fileExtention = postImage[0].split('.').pop()
        console.log(`EXT ${fileExtention}`)
        const fileName = `${uniqid}.${fileExtention} `

        const reference = firebase.storage().ref(`Posts/images/${fileName}`)

        reference.put(postImage)
            .on(
                firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED,
                snapshot => {
                    console.log(`snapshot ${snapshot.state}`)
                    console.log(`progress ${(snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100}`)
                    if (snapshot.state === firebase.storage.TaskState.SUCCESS) {
                        console.log('Success')
                    }
                },
                error => {
                    unsubscribe()
                    console.log("image upload failed" + error.toString())
                },
                () => {
                    firebase.storage()
                        .ref(`posts/images/${fileName}`)
                        .getDownloadURL()
                        .then((downloadUrl) => {
                            console.log(`file available at ${downloadUrl}`)
                        })

                }

            )
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

here a solution

```
 const [image, setImage] = useState(null);
  const [uploading, setUploading] = useState('')
  useEffect(() => {
    getPermission();
  }, []);

  const getPermission = async () => {
    if (Platform.OS !== "web") {
      const { status } =
        await ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();
      if (status !== "granted") {
        alert("Sorry, we need camera roll permissions to make this work!");
      }
    }
  };

  const pickImage = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
      quality: 1,
    });

    console.log(result);

    if (!result.cancelled) {
      setImage(result.uri);
    }
  };

  const getPictureBlob = (uri) => {
    // https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/2402#issuecomment-443726662
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.onload = function () {
        resolve(xhr.response);
      };
      xhr.onerror = function (e) {
        console.log(e);
        reject(new TypeError("Network request failed"));
      };
      xhr.responseType = "blob";
      xhr.open("GET", image, true);
      xhr.send(null);
    });
  };

  const uploadImageToBucket = async () => {
    let blob;
    try {
      setUploading(true);
      blob = await getPictureBlob(image);

      const ref = await storage.ref().child(uuid.v4());
      const snapshot = await ref.put(blob);

      return await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
    } catch (e) {
      alert(e.message);
    } finally {
      blob.close();
      setUploading(false);
    }
  };
```